# For loop that continues one at a time

Tags: java, for-loop, signals, wait, notify

**I don't need an answer any more**

I am trying to create a method, with a for loop in another for loop. It is a sorting algorithm, but in the example I will just use a System.out.println() to keep it simple.
I want the for loop to "continue" only one "step", when the right mouse button is pressed. (left would be ok, too).

so this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=3; i++) {
   for(int e = 0; e<=10; e++) {
      System.out.println("Hello!");
   }
}
```

would print "Hello!" thirty times in the console. What I want to do, is to run these for loops, but with some sort of notifier or waiting condition, so it only prints "Hello!" when I clicked the mouse. I can click thirty times and then the method is finished.
I hope you understand what I mean; a for loop, waiting for some input/notification/...

EDIT:
a lot of people misunderstood my problem :/ the problem is not the mouse listener! I have tons of them I know how they work. The problem is that I want a for loop that only loops once and then waits again!

thanks!

Comment: Use. A. Debugger.

Comment: If you want to react to mouse events, you have to create a GUI application.

Comment: You can use Java GUI. This question resembles the question in this link [How to wait for mouse click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667074/how-to-wait-for-a-mouse-click)

Comment: the problem is not the mouse listener! I have tons of them I know how they work. The problem is that I want a for loop that only loops once and then waits again!

Comment: Your loop will need to wait on a barrier of some kind, like a Semaphore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved! I used a bunch of booleans which told the loop to wait or not to

Comment: So what exactly was your solution.  Your answer is very vague

Comment: I actually made a `while` loop which only increases e if a boolean is set to true. It then automatically sets it to false again and iterates without doing anything until the boolean is set to true again and so on and so forth (until e is big enough)

Answer (score 0):

Look up MouseAdapter in the Java Documentation on how to receive mouse events and write the above code in your own actionListener method.

Comment: you misunderstood me :( the problem is not the mouse listener! I have tons of them I know how they work. The problem is that I want a for loop that only loops once and then waits again!